# What does the notation $\mathbf{Lt}$ signify in a limit?

Tags: limits, notation

The author of a book I'm reading defines the Dirac delta-function as

$$
\delta(\omega_0-\omega) = \frac{2}{\pi}\mathbf{Lt}_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin^2\left(\frac 1 2 (\omega_0-\omega)t\right)}{(\omega_0-\omega)^2t}.
$$

Does the symbol $\mathbf{Lt}$ have any special significance, or is it just a normal limit? I've never seen this notation before. The way he uses it, it seems to be just an ordinary limit, but since he doesn't use the universal $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$ notation, I suspect it might have some additional significance?

The book is "The Quantum Theory of Light" by Loudon.

Comment: Is this book in some specialized field like signals and systems or linear systems theory? Maybe provide the title of the book. Regards

Comment: I added the name of the book. The field is quantum optics.

Comment: Seeing as it's a Dirac delta, the limit probably denotes a [nascent limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Representations_of_the_delta_function)

Comment: A nascent limit is consistent with the development that comes after the above definition, EuYu is most likely right.